# how to animate a div within a boundry

Tags: javascript, jquery

To preface, this is my first time using JQuery so i dont really know the syntax and i'm a beginning programmer in javascript and I'm new to stackoverflow too. So apologies in advance.

Also apologies in advance if this has been asked before. This should be simple, yet somehow i can't figure it out and it's a little hard to search for.

Problem: I need my animation to be moving within a div boundry that it's in.

i tried changing the window in var h and var w to the id of my container, it doesn't work:

```
var h = $(#ghosts).height() - 75;
var w = $(#ghosts).height() - 75;



// html
<div id="playBoxProperties">
            <div id="playBox"> // play area
              <div id="ghosts"> // container for all 8 ghosts

                <div id='g1' class="boo"> // one of the moving ghosts
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
        </div>


// to randomize the movement

function randomPos() { 

  var h = $(window).height() - 75; // i need to change the window, to something else.
  var w = $(window).width() - 75; //  But i dont know what.

  var newH = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var newW = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [newH, newW];

}

// animation to move around

function animateDiv(divID) {

  var newPos = randomPos();

  $(divID).animate({ top: newPos[0], left: newPos[1] }, 4000, function () {
    animateDiv(divID);
  });
```

I expect it to be inside the black box

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: I dont think it says anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subtract the currently iterating ghost element size from the random coordinate relative to the parent wrapper:

- pass the parent and the animating child like `randomPos($chi, $par)`
- Use Strings as your selectors. `$(#ghosts);` should be `$('#ghosts');`
- Create a small jQuery plugin if you want: `$.fn.animateGhosts`. Use it like `$ghosts.animateGhosts();`

```js
const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const $ghostsWrapper = $('#ghosts');
const randomPos = ($chi, $par) => ({ // Randomize position
  x: ~~(Math.random() * ($par.width() - $chi.width())),
  y: ~~(Math.random() * ($par.height() - $chi.height()))
});

$.fn.animateGhosts = function() {
  function anim() {
    const pos = randomPos($(this), $ghostsWrapper);
    $(this).stop().delay(rand(100, 500)).animate({
      left: pos.x,
      top: pos.y,
    }, rand(1000, 4000), anim.bind(this));
  }
  return this.each(anim);
};

$('.boo').animateGhosts();
```

```css
#ghosts {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}

.boo {
  position: absolute;
  background: fuchsia;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ghosts">
  <div class="boo">1</div>
  <div class="boo">2</div>
  <div class="boo">3</div>
  <div class="boo">4</div>
  <div class="boo">5</div>
  <div class="boo">6</div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

### Better performance using CSS `transition` and `translate`

Here's an example that will use the power of CSS3 to move our elements in a hardware (GPU) accelerated fashion. Notice how, when slowing down, the elements are not zigzagging to the round pixel value (since jQuery animates `top` and `left`).
Instead we'll use `transition` for the CSS3 animation timing and `translate(x, y)` for the positions:

```js
const rand = (min, max) => Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
const $ghostsWrapper = $('#ghosts');
const randomPos = ($chi, $par) => ({ // Randomize position
  x: ~~(Math.random() * ($par.width() - $chi.width())),
  y: ~~(Math.random() * ($par.height() - $chi.height()))
});

$.fn.animateGhosts = function() {
  function anim() {
    const pos = randomPos($(this), $ghostsWrapper);
    $(this).css({
      transition: `${rand(1, 4)}s ${rand(0.1, 0.4)}s ease`, // Speed(s) Pause(s)
      transform: `translate(${pos.x}px, ${pos.y}px)`
    }).one('transitionend', anim.bind(this));
  }
  return this.each(anim);
};

$('.boo').animateGhosts();
```

```css
#ghosts {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
  outline: 2px solid #000;
}

.boo {
  position: absolute;
  background: fuchsia;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="ghosts">
  <div class="boo">1</div>
  <div class="boo">2</div>
  <div class="boo">3</div>
  <div class="boo">4</div>
  <div class="boo">5</div>
  <div class="boo">6</div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: @kannonf have you set `.boo`'s width and height? As you can see the code works, so perhaps you should take some time and figure out what's going on in your code. Creating a [mcve] would be helpful, without your CSS (or other stuff) is hard to tell

Comment: im sorry im stupid >.<
i think i forgot to change the relative and absolute

Comment: hopefully the ghosts are happy now ;) @kannonf

Comment: so i'm curious, these 2 both get the job done. But the last one is more efficient?

Comment: @kannonf yes, because  as you can see the ghosts are hardware (GPU) accelerated due the CSS3 rules `transition` and `transform`. You can notice that the animation is more fluid (they do not zig-zag pixel-by-pixel, since jQuery animates `top` and `left` CSS properties).

Comment: ahh i see, i havent actually tried the 2 way, i'm going to try it now. Also regarding not seeing my css, you actually guessed it, just that i had seperate ghosts rules using their each id (this is where the absolute and relative screwed me up). But i decided to just collate them together with the class boo.

Comment: so I tried your 2nd way, the animation actually doesnt work. It stoppped completely on the top left hand side (it's still inside the black box). This time I made sure the absolute and relative were correct. (Also, stackoverflow tells me to chat, but i'm new so I cant chat yet).

Comment: @kannonf strange, noting changes in CSS and HTML, just the `JS` part... What browser do you use?

Comment: i'm using firefox. But regardless, i'm very thankful for your help. (I kinda like how it stutters at the end actually).

I think i need to learn more about all of this before diving into it.

Comment: @kannonf Ahh, I thought for a split second that you use some ancient IE :). It should work perfectly fine... Not sure what might be the issue in your code right now...

Comment: So i tried it again, it runs, but it takes a few second for the animation to start. I didnt do anything differently, maybe it has something to do with the jquery library?

Comment: Okay last comment because i dont want to clutter (if it's not already haha). So i refreshed my browser and it's stopped again. I also tried it in chrome and it's stuck in the same place too; inside the black box, top left hand corner. I didnt make any changes at all.
But anyway, once again thank you for the help. I really really appreciate it :D

Comment: Create a jsFiddle so I can take a look